# Linked objects ? two objects in the view port. but one has no properties of name why?

Tags: modeling, objects, 3d-view, outliner

I have a Piston object composed of two parts. The piston container has a name in the outliner qa.001.a. but the second seems to be totally invisible in the outliner and can only be selected and manipulated from the viewport.

How is this possible?  How can I make the second invisible object a true object with its name in the outliner?

[image]
[image]

Comment: qa.001.b is child of qa.001.a : open qa.001.a branch in the outliner, you'll see it